# How to resize image inside <Button> in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm new to .NET Maui and XAML and I'm trying to make a simple button menu.

When I uso  the image fills in all the space and text label doesnt show. Buttons are intented to show icons, but when using the icons they also get streched.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-7.0

Note

While Button defines an ImageSource property, that allows you to display a image on the Button, this property is intended to be used when displaying a small icon next to the Button text.

---

This is the code and result:

```
    <Button HeightRequest="300"
            WidthRequest="300"
            BorderColor="Blue"
            BorderWidth="3"
            BackgroundColor="Grey"
            Text="TEXT INSIDE BUTTON"
            FontSize="12"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            ImageSource="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg"
            ContentLayout="Top, 1">

    </Button>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvZr0.png)

---

What I would like to achieve is something similar to card with border, image and text

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhKHk.png)

NET MAUI documentation, Youtube tutorial and so on. Pretty new to XAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no a such Button control can achieve the effect you want. So you can use a control to contain the image and the text. And then use the TapGestureRecognizer to deal with the clicked event. Such as:

```
        <Frame HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" BorderColor="Red" Margin="20" >
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="-10">
                <Image Source="image.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Margin="-10"/>
                <Label Margin="0" Text="this is text" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
```

The Margin property can be used to adjust the fine position of the view.

And in the Page.cs:

```
 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
       // you can do the work you want when the button clicked
    }
```

The result picture:

[image]

In addition, you can refer to this case about [how to change xamarin frame border thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/533005/how-to-change-xamarin-frame-border-thickness) to set the frame's border width.

Comment: Thanks Liyun! I wanted to use Button but using Frame as you said was probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DevExpres [SimpleButton](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.Controls.SimpleButton) component ([DevExpress .NET MAUI suite](https://www.devexpress.com/maui/) is currently available free of charge):

```xml
<dxc:SimpleButton Padding="0">
   <Image HeightReqiest="24" WidthReqiest="24" />
</dxc:SimpleButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Button I kind of manage to solve the problem too.

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*">
  <Button x:Name="ButtonClick" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="My Text" ImageSource="image.png" BorderColor="red" Style="{StaticResource bstyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Reference to Style

```
<Style x:Key="bstyle1" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="MaximumHeightRequest" Value="200"/>
  <Setter Property="MaximumWidthRequest" Value="200"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="25,5,25,5"/>
  <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
  <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="3"/>
  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="7"/>
  <Setter Property="ContentLayout" Value="Top, 0"/>
  <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="3"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="red"/>
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this on Android and iOS you could use [FreakyControls](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls)'s FreakyButton control

The documentation for it can be found here : https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/wiki/FreakyButton

```
 <freakyControls:FreakyButton
        Animation="FadeAndScale"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        BorderColor="Black"
        BusyColor="White"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        IconSize="30"
        LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"
        Text="Edged icon trailing with fade and scale"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        <freakyControls:FreakyButton.TrailingIcon>
            <Image Source="calendar.png" />
        </freakyControls:FreakyButton.TrailingIcon>
 </freakyControls:FreakyButton>
```

It let's you customize your button and has a lot of other helpful properties.